# Reuse AlertDialog title layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-alertdialog

The question is simple: where can I find the name of the `AlertDialog` title layout so I can reuse it in my app's layouts? Googling hasn't helped me much, so I just hope someone can provide a quick answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you mean do u want styles or layout `>@android:layout/alert_dialog_holo<`

```
<>/android-sdk/platforms/android-15/data/res/values/styles.xml


 <!-- Dialog styles -->

    <style name="AlertDialog.Holo" parent="AlertDialog">
        <item name="fullDark">@android:drawable/dialog_full_holo_dark</item>
        <item name="topDark">@android:drawable/dialog_top_holo_dark</item>
        <item name="centerDark">@android:drawable/dialog_middle_holo_dark</item>
        <item name="bottomDark">@android:drawable/dialog_bottom_holo_dark</item>
        <item name="fullBright">@android:drawable/dialog_full_holo_dark</item>
        <item name="topBright">@android:drawable/dialog_top_holo_dark</item>
        <item name="centerBright">@android:drawable/dialog_middle_holo_dark</item>
        <item name="bottomBright">@android:drawable/dialog_bottom_holo_dark</item>
        <item name="bottomMedium">@android:drawable/dialog_bottom_holo_dark</item>
        <item name="centerMedium">@android:drawable/dialog_middle_holo_dark</item>
        <item name="layout">@android:layout/alert_dialog_holo</item>
        <item name="listLayout">@android:layout/select_dialog_holo</item>
        <item name="progressLayout">@android:layout/progress_dialog_holo</item>
        <item name="horizontalProgressLayout">@android:layout/alert_dialog_progress_holo</item>
        <item name="listItemLayout">@android:layout/select_dialog_item_holo</item>
        <item name="multiChoiceItemLayout">@android:layout/select_dialog_multichoice_holo</item>
        <item name="singleChoiceItemLayout">@android:layout/select_dialog_singlechoice_holo</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: The layout itself, but just the title part layout, not the whole AlertDialog.

Comment: ya that you can find in platforms @android:layout/alert_dialog